# Creating Superset and subset according to a threshold value

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to find supersets and subsets for values included in a column(here for letter column) from an excel file. The data looks like this:

| id | letter |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A, B, D, E, F |
| 2 | B, C |
| 3 | B |
| 4 | D, B |
| 5 | B, D, A |
| 6 | X, Y, Z |
| 7 | X, Y |
| 8 | E, D |
| 9 | G |
| 10 | G |

I would like to show and store that relation in the file( including subsets and their supersets) according to a threshold value(for ex. equal or bigger than 50% score). For e.g.:
'B' is subset of 'A,B,D,E,F' but threshold is 1/5=0.2 so it wont be included in subset. Also id of 'A,B,D,E,F' wont be included itself as subset.
Output file:

| id | letter | sub-ids |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A, B, D, E, F | 5 |
| 2 | B, C | 3 |
| 4 | D, B | 3 |
| 6 | X, Y, Z | 7 |
| 9 | G | 10 |

The code I tried is:

```
import itertools
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    'letter': ['A, B, D, E, F','B, C','B','D, B','B, D, A','X, Y, Z','X, Y','E, D','G','G']})

lst = df['letter'].values.tolist()
lst = list(tuple(item.strip() for item in x.split(',')) for x in lst)
out = lst[:] 

for tup1,tup2 in itertools.combinations(lst, 2):
    a, b = (tup1, tup2) if len(tup1) < len(tup2) else (tup2, tup1)
    if all(elem in b for elem in a) and a in out:
        out.remove(a)
    if all(elem in b for elem in a) and 0.5<=len(a)/len(b)<=1.0:
        out.append(b)
filt = list(map(', '.join, out))
df2 = df.loc[df['letter'].isin(filt), :].drop_duplicates(subset='letter')
print(df2)
```

Comment: Isn't `'B'` a subset of `'B, C'` at 50%? Also, what if a row is a subset of several other ones, e.g., hypothetically, `'B, C, D'` vs. two rows: `'A, B, C, D'` and `'B, C, D, E'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility (admittedly not the fastest) could be:

```py
import pandas as pd

df: pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame([
    ["A, B, D, E, F"], ["B, C"], ["B"], ["D, B"], ["B, D, A"], ["X, Y, Z"], ["X, Y"],
    ["E, D"], ["G"], ["G"]
], columns=["letters"])

threshold = 0.5


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sub_ids = []
    for i in range(len(df)):
        temp = []
        curr_letters_i = df.iloc[i]["letters"].replace(" ", "").split(",")
        for j in range(len(df)):
            if i == j:
                continue
            curr_letters_j = df.iloc[j]["letters"].replace(" ", "").split(",")
            if not all([letter in curr_letters_i for letter in curr_letters_j]):
                continue
            if len(curr_letters_j)/len(curr_letters_i) >= threshold:
                temp.append(f"{j}")
        sub_ids.append(",".join(temp))
    df["sub-ids"] = sub_ids
    print(df)
```

This returns

```
         letters sub-ids
0  A, B, D, E, F       4
1           B, C       2
2              B        
3           D, B       2
4        B, D, A       3
5        X, Y, Z       6
6           X, Y        
7           E, D        
8              G       9
9              G       8
```

Then, if we want to filter out the lines that are not super-sets of other, we can add `new_df = df.loc[df["sub-ids"] != ""]` before the `print`. In this case, printing `new_df` gives

```
         letters sub-ids
0  A, B, D, E, F       4
1           B, C       2
3           D, B       2
4        B, D, A       3
5        X, Y, Z       6
8              G       9
9              G       8
```

To account for IDs that may not be numerical or in order, we may replace `temp.append(f"{j}")` by `temp.append(f"{df.iloc[j]['id']}")`. This gives:

```
     id        letters sub-ids
0   ID1  A, B, D, E, F     ID5
1   ID2           B, C     ID3
3   ID4           D, B     ID3
4   ID5        B, D, A     ID4
5   ID6        X, Y, Z     ID7
8   ID9              G    ID10
9  ID10              G     ID9
```

Then, if we wanted to add the similarity score as a column, we could introduce a `sub_scores` variable:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    sub_ids = []
    sub_scores = []
    for i in range(len(df)):
        temp_sub_ids = []
        temp_sub_scores = []
        curr_letters_i = df.iloc[i]["letters"].replace(" ", "").split(",")
        for j in range(len(df)):
            if i == j:
                continue
            curr_letters_j = df.iloc[j]["letters"].replace(" ", "").split(",")
            if not all([letter in curr_letters_i for letter in curr_letters_j]):
                continue
            if len(curr_letters_j)/len(curr_letters_i) >= threshold:
                temp_sub_ids.append(f"{df.iloc[j]['id']}")
                temp_sub_scores.append(f"{len(curr_letters_j)/len(curr_letters_i):.2f}")
        sub_ids.append(",".join(temp_sub_ids))
        sub_scores.append(temp_sub_scores)
    df["sub-ids"] = sub_ids
    df["sub-scores"] = sub_scores
    new_df = df.loc[df["sub-ids"] != ""]
    print(new_df)
```

This produces

```
     id        letters sub-ids sub-scores
0   ID1  A, B, D, E, F     ID5     [0.60]
1   ID2           B, C     ID3     [0.50]
3   ID4           D, B     ID3     [0.50]
4   ID5        B, D, A     ID4     [0.67]
5   ID6        X, Y, Z     ID7     [0.67]
8   ID9              G    ID10     [1.00]
9  ID10              G     ID9     [1.00]
```

Comment: Thank you. If I want to remove rows with null sub-ids what should I add?

Comment: Also, here I give ids in an order. But in file there is no order. So if I want to make it with specific id column, what should I do?

Comment: I edited for the filtering of null sub-ids lines. What do you mean "make it with specific id column"?

Comment: I mean not with a temp. Because in original file, it is not as 1,2,3,4.. It comes with non-consecutive numbers.

Comment: I have edited the answer, it should satisfy your needs. The `temp` is nothing but the list of ids of the cells for which the current cell is a super-set. It is then joined with comas in the case where there would be multiple sub-sets for a single cell.

Comment: Thank you again. I just want to ask a last question. If I want to add a new column with similarity score, for each sub-id like (0.82 ,0.85 ..). What should I do?

Comment: Thank you so much. I am trying to find unique groups that any element of a group should not be appeared in other groups' elements. For example if I have ["F"] then it will be unique. How can I make this?

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: Any element of a group should not be appeared in another groups' elements. So if I have another row with ["K"] then because K is not any other groups' elements then it will be a unique group. I just put it as a new question post. Could you please have a look?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75738565/get-unique-groups-from-a-set-of-group/75739133#75739133

Comment: I answered your other question