# Get unique groups from a set of group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to find unique groups in a column(here for letter column) from an excel file. The data looks like this:

| id | letter |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A, B, D, E, F |
| 3 | B, C |
| 2 | B |
| 75 | T |
| 54 | K, M |
| 9 | D, B |
| 23 | B, D, A |
| 34 | X, Y, Z |
| 67 | X, Y |
| 12 | E, D |
| 15 | G |
| 10 | G |
| 11 | F |

Any element of a group should not be appeared in another groups' elements. According to previous table the output file should be like this:

| id | letter |
| --- | --- |
| 75 | T |
| 54 | K, M |

Because any elements of these groups havent been shared with another group.

The code I tried:

```
df: pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame([
["A, B, D, E, F"], ["B, C"], ["B"], ["T"],  ["K, M"], ["D, B"], ["B, D, A"], ["X, Y, Z"], ["X, Y"],
["E, D"], ["G"], ["G"]], columns=["letters"])
if __name__ == "__main__":
sub_ids=[]
for i in range(len(df)):
    temp_sub_ids = []
    curr_letters_i = df.iloc[i]["letters"].replace(" ", "").split(",")
    for j in range(len(df)):
        if i == j:
            continue
        curr_letters_j = df.iloc[j]["letters"].replace(" ", "").split(",")
        if not any([letter in curr_letters_i for letter in curr_letters_j]):
       
            temp_sub_ids.append(f"{df.iloc[j]['id']}")
       
    sub_ids.append(",".join(temp_sub_ids))
df["sub-ids"] = sub_ids
print(df)
```

With this code, it gives each ids as sub ids that dont have any shared letter. But I want to search for all letter groups and if there is not any shared letter with other groups, then it will be as unique.

Comment: Normally you will want to show your code from your attempt. Have you already downloaded the library to access xlsx files in python? If it's a CSV file you don't need a 3rd party lib

Comment: Please see [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). "*Show me how to solve this coding problem*" [is off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236). You have to [make an honest attempt at the solution](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), and then ask a specific question about your implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To continue [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75684898/16521194) from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75684444/16521194), I would only add a simple unicity test as a new column to the dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df: pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, "A, B, D, E, F"], [3, "B, C"], [2, "B"], [75, "T"], [54, "K, M"],
    [9, "D, B"], [23, "B, D, A"], [34, "X, Y, Z"], [67, "X, Y"],
    [12, "E, D"], [15, "G"], [10, "G"], [11, "F"]
], columns=["id", "letters"])

threshold = 0.5


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sub_ids = []
    sub_scores = []
    sub_unique = []
    for i in range(len(df)):
        temp_sub_ids = []
        temp_sub_scores = []
        temp_unique = True
        curr_letters_i = df.iloc[i]["letters"].replace(" ", "").split(",")
        for j in range(len(df)):
            if i == j:
                continue
            curr_letters_j = df.iloc[j]["letters"].replace(" ", "").split(",")
            if any([letter in curr_letters_i for letter in curr_letters_j]):
                temp_unique = False
            if not all([letter in curr_letters_i for letter in curr_letters_j]):
                continue
            if len(curr_letters_j)/len(curr_letters_i) >= threshold:
                temp_sub_ids.append(f"{df.iloc[j]['id']}")
                temp_sub_scores.append(f"{len(curr_letters_j)/len(curr_letters_i):.2f}")
        sub_ids.append(",".join(temp_sub_ids))
        sub_scores.append(temp_sub_scores)
        sub_unique.append(temp_unique)
    df["sub-ids"] = sub_ids
    df["sub-scores"] = sub_scores
    df["unicity"] = sub_unique
    print(df)
```

This produces

```
    id        letters sub-ids sub-scores  unicity
0    1  A, B, D, E, F      23     [0.60]    False
1    3           B, C       2     [0.50]    False
2    2              B                 []    False
3   75              T                 []     True
4   54           K, M                 []     True
5    9           D, B       2     [0.50]    False
6   23        B, D, A       9     [0.67]    False
7   34        X, Y, Z      67     [0.67]    False
8   67           X, Y                 []    False
9   12           E, D                 []    False
10  15              G      10     [1.00]    False
11  10              G      15     [1.00]    False
12  11              F                 []    False
```

Which can be filtered (`print(df.loc[df["unicity"] == True]`) to

```
   id letters sub-ids sub-scores  unicity
3  75       T                 []     True
4  54    K, M                 []     True
```

Answer (score 2):

Algorithm:

- appending an auxiliary column `letter_` based on splitting `letter` column on regex separator having each group as a list of values/elements
- explode/expand `letter_` so that each value is placed on a separate row
- map each `letter_` value to its frequency (count of its occurrences)
- filter `letter` (initial groups) which only have items with a single occurrence (max count is `1`)

---

```
df = df.assign(letter_=df['letter'].str.split(r'\s*,\s*')).explode('letter_')
df['letter_'] = df['letter_'].map(df['letter_'].value_counts())
df = df.groupby('letter').filter(lambda x: x['letter_'].max() == 1)\
    .drop_duplicates().drop('letter_', axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

---

```
   id letter
0  75      T
1  54   K, M
```